# pgfplots linear regression for the wrong column

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

The following MWE correctly plots the `Y` column when it is plotted directly (black points). However, a linear regression specified for the `Y` column actually fits to the `Z` column if the `Y` column is the last one (black dashed line). If `Y` is the second column, the regression is for the correct column (blue dashed line). How can I have the linear regression be for the `Y` column even though it is the last column?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick={1,...,6}]
\pgfplotstableread{%
X Z Y
1 3 0
2 4 1
3 5 2
4 6 3
}\test
\addplot[only marks, mark=*] table[x=X, y=Y] {\test};
% Here be dragons
\addplot[no markers,dashed,x=X,y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] table {\test};
% Here is normal
\addplot[no markers,dashed,x=X,y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}},blue]
table{%
X Y Z
1 0 3
2 1 4
3 2 5
4 3 6
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: incorrect linear regression]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `y={create col...}` option needs to go in `\addplot table [<options>]`, not `\addplot [<options>] table`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ytick={1,...,6}]
\pgfplotstableread{%
X Z Y
1 3 0
2 4 1
3 5 2
4 6 3
}\test
\addplot[only marks, mark=*] table[x=X, y=Y] {\test};
\addplot[no markers,dashed, red] table [x=X,y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] {\test};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I move the `y={create col...}` to after the `table`, trying to fit any columns with `nan` will not work, and the solution here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173908/32374 was to put the `y={create col...}` to just after the `addplot`. Any idea what the difference is?

Comment: @darthbith: That solution only looked like it worked, but actually no regression line was calculated. I've added a different answer to that question.