# PGFPlots & .CSV - Read first 301 lines only, or "skip last n=?"?

Tags: pgfplots, csv

Alright, I am dealing with a test setup that outputs a CSV file.  It has columns of data, the longest it will ever be is 301 lines of data I need every time, unless it fails then it will kick out early.  However, then there is a blank line, then the titles again, and an average of the entire column above it.

So the guy who programmed it made the footer of the CSV like a summary area.  At first I was using gnuplot and this read the file no problem:

```
gnuplot example code snippet: 
plot 'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 3 with line lc rgb "blue", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 4 with line lc rgb "orange", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 5 with line lc rgb "green", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 6 with line lc rgb "brown", \
-12 lt rgb "red"
set title "Aux Channel"
set yrange [*:-17]
plot 'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 7 with line lc rgb "blue", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 8 with line lc rgb "orange", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 9 with line lc rgb "green", \
'temp4.csv' every ::1::301 using 10 with line lc rgb "brown", \
```

So their line skip is fancy and can be abused to do that. And that still would have choked on the failing datasets with less than 301 lines once it got to the footer section.

Now I moved to latex because the PDF I was able to make looks amazing and I'd like to automate this report generation, the CSV looks like below:

```
Iteration,Sample,MSE ChA,MSE ChB,MSE ChC,MSE ChD,MSE_remote ChA,MSE_remote ChB,MSE_remote ChC,MSE_remote ChD,
1,0,-22.198,-21.981,-22.341,-21.366,-21.573,-21.573,-21.525,-20.588,
1,1,-22.468,-21.815,-22.38,-21.564,-21.577,-21.561,-21.562,-20.701,
1,2,-21.929,-22.087,-22.409,-21.741,-21.588,-21.561,-21.553,-20.6,
1,3,-22.297,-22.347,-22.234,-21.805,-21.549,-21.55,-21.548,-20.592,
1,4,-22.417,-22.183,-22.352,-21.764,-21.568,-21.552,-21.567,-20.587,
1,5,-22.286,-22.123,-22.363,-21.638,-21.564,-21.66,-21.576,-20.611,
2,0,-21.219,-15.412,-22.314,-21.956,-19.949,-21.554,-21.57,-20.583,
2,1,-20.814,-21.962,-22.341,-22.284,-20.602,-21.604,-21.564,-19.845,
2,2,-21.133,-22.157,-22.114,-21.865,-20.58,-21.555,-21.545,-19.773,
2,3,-20.719,-19.621,-22.338,-22.345,-20.488,-21.558,-21.546,-20.534,
2,4,-20.831,-21.867,-22.511,-21.825,-20.636,-21.56,-21.565,-20.586,
2,5,-20.667,-21.865,-22.332,-22.168,-20.585,-21.635,-21.554,-20.338,
3,0,-22.095,-21.782,-22.424,-21.875,-20.828,-21.584,-21.73,-20.585,
3,1,-22.196,-21.782,-22.393,-22.187,-21.563,-22.452,-22.059,-20.616,
3,2,-21.314,-21.821,-22.354,-21.67,-21.552,-22.63,-21.533,-20.622,
3,3,-21.756,-22.059,-22.334,-21.797,-21.077,-22.375,-21.618,-20.65,
3,4,-21.803,-22,-22.31,-21.846,-20.795,-22.633,-22.645,-20.588,
3,5,-21.929,-18.391,-22.369,-21.983,-21.529,-22.555,-22.634,-20.592,
4,0,-21.213,-21.889,-22.382,-21.59,-21.565,-22.634,-22.661,-20.667,
4,1,-20.721,-21.466,-22.352,-21.821,-21.798,-22.549,-22.664,-20.716,
4,2,-20.969,-21.992,-21.973,-21.441,-21.562,-22.646,-22.651,-20.636,
4,3,-21.24,-21.887,-22.62,-21.312,-21.543,-22.644,-22.636,-20.598,
4,4,-21.211,-21.752,-22.358,-21.463,-21.87,-22.63,-22.643,-20.594,
4,5,-20.816,-21.811,-22.426,-21.703,-21.72,-22.645,-22.656,-20.634,
5,0,-21.287,-21.488,-22.398,-21.912,-21.559,-22.643,-22.576,-21.569,
5,1,-20.923,-21.524,-21.873,-21.042,-22.64,-22.701,-22.635,-21.543,
5,2,-21.388,-21.9,-22.271,-21.809,-21.837,-22.646,-22.32,-21.543,
5,3,-20.869,-21.846,-22.155,-21.398,-21.557,-22.643,-22.652,-21.514,
5,4,-20.938,-21.66,-22.395,-21.417,-22.63,-22.649,-22.636,-21.551,
5,5,-21.271,-21.867,-22.533,-21.405,-22.633,-22.657,-22.651,-21.563,
6,0,-22.198,-21.337,-21.844,-21.737,-19.804,-21.555,-21.564,-19.793,
6,1,-22.278,-22.382,-22.4,-21.821,-20.584,-22.617,-21.555,-19.729,
6,2,-22.371,-21.386,-22.369,-21.735,-20.587,-21.593,-21.101,-19.707,
6,3,-22.226,-22.262,-22.413,-21.944,-20.594,-21.578,-20.646,-19.726,
6,4,-21.832,-22.378,-22.464,-21.624,-20.593,-21.582,-21.538,-19.738,
6,5,-21.741,-22.356,-22.354,-21.445,-20.592,-21.629,-21.303,-19.74,
7,0,-21.881,-22.011,-22.317,-21.852,-22.606,-21.555,-21.571,-20.657,
7,1,-21.877,-21.65,-22.358,-21.66,-21.565,-21.609,-21.587,-20.587,
7,2,-22.127,-21.715,-22.502,-21.384,-22.136,-21.588,-21.571,-20.58,
7,3,-22.239,-22.125,-22.286,-21.256,-21.678,-21.565,-21.597,-20.589,
7,4,-21.819,-21.937,-22.535,-21.316,-22.242,-21.595,-21.589,-20.594,
7,5,-21.813,-21.946,-22.522,-21.337,-22.383,-21.597,-21.586,-20.6,
8,0,-20.984,-21.892,-22.389,-21.53,-21.55,-22.629,-21.574,-21.502,
8,1,-21.31,-21.803,-21.778,-21.506,-21.539,-22.431,-21.673,-21.57,
8,2,-21.221,-21.827,-22.267,-21.84,-20.65,-21.559,-21.753,-21.567,
8,3,-21.353,-21.79,-21.811,-21.715,-21.254,-21.83,-21.544,-21.568,
8,4,-21.141,-21.867,-22.262,-21.614,-20.724,-22.626,-22.066,-21.561,
8,5,-21.421,-21.75,-22.129,-21.889,-21.434,-21.704,-21.877,-21.578,
9,0,-21.967,-22.104,-22.17,-21.848,-21.484,-22.431,-21.553,-20.603,
9,1,-22.367,-21.825,-22.314,-21.854,-20.919,-21.865,-21.565,-20.64,
9,2,-21.795,-21.461,-22.198,-21.294,-21.565,-21.6,-21.551,-20.588,
9,3,-22.435,-22.312,-22.172,-21.921,-21.563,-21.645,-21.597,-20.623,
9,4,-22.245,-21.916,-22.187,-21.84,-21.5,-22.552,-21.553,-20.68,
9,5,-22.343,-21.668,-22.336,-21.854,-21.389,-22.466,-21.564,-20.667,
10,0,-21.227,-21.846,-22.682,-21.333,-21.577,-22.641,-21.566,-21.528,
10,1,-21.312,-22.349,-22.328,-21.776,-21.568,-22.622,-21.562,-21.557,
10,2,-20.832,-21.689,-22.297,-21.244,-21.512,-22.613,-21.818,-21.519,
10,3,-21.252,-21.998,-22.211,-21.166,-21.564,-22.615,-22.469,-21.551,
10,4,-21.246,-21.852,-22.468,-21.392,-21.562,-21.653,-21.65,-20.635,
10,5,-20.31,-21.873,-22.157,-21.273,-21.575,-22.38,-22.369,-21.552,
11,0,-22.148,-22.002,-21.985,-21.731,-21.169,-21.564,-21.49,-18.936,
11,1,-22.387,-22.404,-22.358,-21.638,-21.429,-21.571,-21.521,-18.933,
11,2,-22.08,-22.085,-22.291,-21.654,-20.991,-21.555,-21.501,-19.685,
11,3,-21.875,-22.332,-22.343,-22.258,-20.842,-21.56,-20.728,-18.96,
11,4,-22.301,-21.998,-21.873,-21.626,-20.593,-21.603,-21.536,-19.671,
11,5,-22.082,-22.176,-22.019,-21.624,-20.592,-21.576,-21.548,-19.025,
12,0,-22.354,-21.836,-22.363,-21.807,-20.556,-21.562,-21.644,-18.947,
12,1,-22.226,-19.106,-22.347,-21.636,-20.663,-21.558,-21.65,-18.909,
12,2,-21.76,-21.844,-22.446,-21.821,-20.62,-21.609,-21.724,-19.716,
12,3,-21.793,-21.815,-22.356,-21.954,-21.229,-21.549,-21.602,-19.13,
12,4,-21.856,-21.562,-22.513,-21.721,-20.759,-21.583,-21.743,-18.939,
12,5,-21.797,-21.254,-22.349,-22.136,-21.003,-21.568,-22.106,-19.653,
13,0,-21.431,-17.446,-22.221,-21.825,-20.558,-21.403,-21.563,-21.558,
13,1,-21.256,-17.741,-22.378,-21.793,-20.595,-20.606,-21.572,-21.573,
13,2,-21.296,-21.774,-22.459,-21.819,-20.043,-21.523,-21.575,-21.582,
13,3,-21.374,-21.455,-22.358,-22.219,-20.546,-21.504,-21.514,-21.562,
13,4,-21.494,-18.749,-22.444,-21.83,-20.599,-21.208,-21.535,-21.546,
13,5,-21.327,-21.275,-22.336,-21.842,-20.483,-20.595,-21.54,-21.59,
14,0,-21.666,-21.834,-22.349,-21.554,-21.22,-21.655,-21.542,-21.56,
14,1,-21.741,-22.108,-22.367,-21.756,-20.603,-21.748,-21.582,-21.915,
14,2,-21.392,-21.707,-22.213,-21.474,-21.527,-22.646,-21.555,-21.644,
14,3,-21.124,-21.417,-22.008,-21.869,-20.595,-22.049,-21.532,-21.552,
14,4,-21.323,-21.805,-22.393,-21.277,-21.525,-21.59,-21.555,-21.571,
14,5,-21.29,-21.795,-21.807,-21.954,-21.137,-21.882,-21.559,-21.589,
15,0,-21.402,-22.193,-22.341,-22.097,-20.59,-21.686,-21.58,-20.593,
15,1,-21.118,-21.844,-22.015,-21.842,-20.59,-21.794,-21.597,-20.576,
15,2,-21.496,-21.795,-21.819,-21.919,-20.59,-22.554,-21.56,-20.594,
15,3,-21.256,-22.085,-22.338,-21.844,-20.585,-22.621,-21.788,-20.604,
15,4,-21.298,-21.858,-22.349,-21.805,-20.625,-21.584,-21.566,-20.667,
15,5,-21.306,-22.243,-21.9,-22.176,-20.637,-21.586,-21.571,-20.605,
16,0,-21.318,-21.827,-21.83,-21.904,-20.567,-21.54,-20.903,-19.635,
16,1,-21.506,-22.265,-21.795,-21.898,-20.284,-21.551,-21.377,-19.696,
16,2,-21.296,-21.927,-21.756,-20.882,-20.572,-21.555,-21.429,-19.741,
16,3,-21.37,-22.354,-21.709,-21.269,-20.618,-21.547,-21.56,-19.724,
16,4,-21.419,-22.384,-21.919,-21.198,-20.598,-21.568,-21.558,-19.718,
16,5,-20.864,-22.293,-21.827,-20.934,-20.562,-21.573,-20.782,-19.721,
17,0,-20.845,-21.636,-21.933,-21.809,-20.593,-21.382,-21.565,-21.093,
17,1,-21.204,-21.719,-21.821,-21.811,-20.603,-20.619,-21.545,-21.508,
17,2,-21.016,-21.803,-22.295,-21.996,-20.789,-20.589,-21.544,-20.631,
17,3,-20.906,-21.844,-22.391,-21.815,-20.615,-20.667,-21.569,-20.767,
17,4,-21.116,-22.04,-22.376,-21.608,-20.666,-21.525,-21.584,-21.559,
17,5,-21.012,-21.394,-21.652,-21.701,-20.606,-20.594,-21.559,-20.569,
18,0,-22.256,-21.836,-22.323,-20.397,-21.515,-21.566,-21.557,-20.587,
18,1,-21.626,-22.334,-22.301,-20.072,-20.847,-21.566,-21.549,-20.533,
18,2,-22.367,-22.271,-22.31,-20.378,-21.53,-21.533,-21.553,-20.65,
18,3,-22.299,-22.008,-22.249,-20.466,-21.511,-21.6,-21.541,-20.646,
18,4,-22.129,-21.768,-21.985,-20.097,-21.52,-21.579,-21.557,-20.632,
18,5,-22.093,-22.428,-22.367,-20.286,-21.566,-21.595,-21.561,-20.597,
19,0,-22.004,-19.488,-22.426,-21.937,-21.627,-21.574,-21.536,-22.244,
19,1,-21.433,-21.935,-22.349,-21.83,-21.571,-21.962,-21.471,-21.592,
19,2,-21.542,-21.817,-22.393,-21.77,-21.569,-21.675,-21.561,-21.691,
19,3,-22.354,-21.809,-22.42,-21.782,-21.522,-21.559,-21.596,-21.886,
19,4,-21.62,-21.933,-22.393,-21.815,-22.625,-21.848,-21.572,-22.171,
19,5,-22.352,-21.766,-22.363,-21.921,-21.694,-21.557,-21.551,-21.566,
20,0,-20.803,-22.204,-22.332,-22.036,-19.746,-20.648,-21.574,-20.581,
20,1,-20.88,-22.008,-22.325,-21.842,-19.731,-20.603,-21.582,-20.078,
20,2,-21.154,-22.131,-22.404,-21.693,-19.727,-20.682,-21.566,-20.615,
20,3,-20.975,-22.354,-22.506,-21.879,-19.75,-20.594,-21.562,-20.586,
20,4,-21.041,-21.287,-22.363,-22.106,-19.753,-20.669,-21.565,-20.57,
20,5,-21.314,-22.049,-21.969,-22.011,-19.729,-20.765,-21.558,-20.582,
21,0,-21.357,-21.904,-22.437,-21.296,-20.964,-20.752,-20.592,-19.712,
21,1,-20.984,-22.312,-22.761,-21.819,-20.728,-20.639,-20.544,-18.96,
21,2,-21.514,-21.906,-22.374,-21.366,-20.607,-20.584,-20.589,-19.685,
21,3,-21.097,-22.108,-22.082,-21.606,-21.452,-20.8,-21.427,-19.722,
21,4,-21.12,-22.256,-22.245,-21.122,-21.545,-20.708,-21.503,-19.78,
21,5,-21.231,-21.784,-22.493,-21.809,-20.719,-20.707,-21.529,-19.719,
22,0,-21.66,-21.819,-22.365,-21.784,-20.226,-21.557,-20.542,-19.677,
22,1,-21.037,-22.114,-22.349,-21.865,-20.443,-21.54,-20.591,-19.678,
22,2,-21.219,-22.387,-22.391,-21.797,-19.851,-21.294,-20.587,-19.716,
22,3,-21.179,-22.284,-22.376,-21.618,-20.294,-21.548,-20.598,-19.548,
22,4,-21.217,-21.801,-22.406,-22.061,-20.429,-21.552,-21.079,-19.718,
22,5,-21.124,-21.856,-22.544,-21.788,-20.563,-21.553,-20.598,-18.919,
23,0,-21.325,-21.842,-22.711,-21.246,-21.46,-21.563,-21.561,-20.604,
23,1,-21.439,-22.347,-21.925,-21.392,-21.561,-21.602,-21.559,-20.624,
23,2,-20.767,-22.063,-22.347,-21.304,-21.601,-21.574,-21.547,-20.592,
23,3,-20.656,-22.239,-22.138,-21.31,-21.561,-21.565,-21.575,-20.598,
23,4,-20.467,-21.958,-22.187,-21.504,-21.557,-21.556,-21.557,-20.588,
23,5,-20.96,-22.142,-22.389,-21.337,-21.391,-21.608,-21.558,-20.778,
24,0,-21.112,-22.155,-22.365,-21.349,-21.533,-22.594,-22.233,-20.584,
24,1,-21.097,-22.053,-22.252,-21.842,-21.505,-22.629,-22.64,-20.573,
24,2,-21.355,-22.183,-22.363,-21.353,-21.56,-22.646,-22.612,-20.549,
24,3,-20.847,-22.148,-22.063,-21.005,-20.982,-22.476,-22.631,-20.568,
24,4,-21.386,-21.941,-22.343,-21.873,-20.966,-22.624,-22.437,-20.547,
24,5,-21.325,-21.817,-22.336,-21.302,-21.455,-21.563,-22.554,-19.867,
25,0,-21.384,-21.944,-22.055,-21.846,-21.528,-21.643,-21.469,-21.559,
25,1,-21.322,-22.36,-22.314,-21.715,-21.581,-21.561,-21.57,-21.564,
25,2,-20.967,-22.019,-22.358,-21.854,-21.624,-21.58,-21.58,-21.557,
25,3,-21.304,-21.793,-22.206,-21.803,-21.573,-21.581,-21.561,-21.405,
25,4,-21.554,-21.975,-22.26,-21.782,-21.565,-21.553,-21.679,-20.95,
25,5,-21.078,-21.54,-22.36,-21.827,-21.67,-21.565,-21.555,-21.554,
26,0,-20.763,-21.817,-22.273,-22.002,-21.468,-21.561,-20.705,-20.525,
26,1,-21.033,-22.002,-22.33,-21.992,-21.555,-21.514,-21.078,-19.914,
26,2,-20.692,-22.213,-22.36,-21.723,-21.58,-21.554,-21.513,-20.42,
26,3,-20.667,-21.776,-22.23,-21.799,-21.556,-21.56,-21.526,-19.787,
26,4,-20.854,-22.343,-22.517,-21.803,-21.643,-21.556,-21.563,-19.97,
26,5,-21.137,-22.354,-22.352,-21.892,-21.541,-21.54,-21.559,-19.833,
27,0,-22.249,-22.215,-22.422,-22.334,-21.538,-21.558,-21.569,-21.573,
27,1,-22.363,-22.341,-22.376,-21.877,-21.569,-21.446,-21.109,-21.563,
27,2,-22.271,-22.153,-22.369,-21.803,-21.549,-21.546,-21.566,-21.543,
27,3,-22.374,-22.356,-22.428,-21.894,-21.558,-21.591,-21.566,-21.553,
27,4,-21.825,-21.996,-22.4,-21.54,-21.256,-21.499,-21.517,-21.573,
27,5,-22.345,-22.185,-22.398,-21.848,-21.541,-21.585,-21.001,-21.72,
28,0,-22.267,-21.805,-22.374,-21.919,-21.56,-21.557,-21.55,-21.539,
28,1,-22.295,-22.021,-22.363,-21.815,-21.547,-21.555,-21.542,-21.032,
28,2,-21.821,-21.867,-22.278,-21.713,-21.172,-21.569,-21.574,-21.556,
28,3,-22.334,-22.065,-22.354,-21.815,-21.25,-21.536,-21.562,-20.839,
28,4,-22.356,-21.66,-22.119,-21.96,-21.539,-21.556,-21.533,-20.686,
28,5,-22.288,-21.799,-22.099,-21.848,-21.54,-21.689,-20.681,-21.557,
29,0,-21.2,-21.793,-22.129,-21.322,-21.558,-21.495,-21.551,-20.586,
29,1,-21.335,-21.715,-22.374,-21.304,-21.637,-21.556,-21.557,-20.581,
29,2,-20.699,-21.916,-22.468,-21.2,-22.581,-21.617,-21.541,-20.12,
29,3,-21.374,-21.987,-22.378,-21.122,-21.695,-21.652,-21.549,-20.591,
29,4,-21.033,-21.784,-22.36,-21.215,-21.567,-21.626,-21.553,-20.584,
29,5,-21.078,-21.79,-22.286,-21.32,-21.6,-22.555,-21.553,-20.571,
30,0,-21.331,-21.941,-22.33,-21.967,-20.725,-21.554,-21.546,-21.525,
30,1,-21.158,-21.715,-22.56,-21.91,-20.561,-21.574,-21.538,-21.262,
30,2,-21.012,-22.053,-22.144,-21.758,-20.707,-21.557,-21.331,-20.881,
30,3,-21.281,-21.842,-22.464,-21.887,-20.612,-21.556,-21.556,-21.465,
30,4,-21.421,-21.875,-22.053,-21.877,-20.606,-21.55,-21.518,-21.465,
30,5,-20.941,-21.463,-22.36,-22.208,-20.661,-21.522,-21.559,-21.527,
31,0,-21.148,-21.9,-22.213,-21.514,-21.544,-21.49,-21.568,-19.821,
31,1,-21.024,-21.948,-21.939,-21.612,-20.637,-21.177,-21.547,-20.504,
31,2,-21.318,-22.065,-22.356,-21.852,-21.532,-21.51,-21.576,-20.591,
31,3,-21.248,-22.306,-21.925,-21.476,-21.516,-20.607,-21.553,-20.293,
31,4,-21.325,-22.082,-22.291,-21.349,-20.442,-21.554,-21.564,-20.516,
31,5,-21.003,-22.389,-22.078,-21.821,-20.623,-20.895,-21.546,-20.581,
32,0,-21.689,-22.063,-22.371,-21.863,-21.551,-22.635,-20.585,-20.591,
32,1,-21.139,-22.295,-22.04,-21.827,-20.995,-21.579,-21.561,-20.569,
32,2,-21.227,-16.514,-21.854,-21.801,-21.566,-21.924,-21.152,-20.596,
32,3,-21.154,-22.234,-22.123,-21.838,-21.564,-22.62,-20.655,-20.57,
32,4,-21.748,-22.089,-22.428,-21.793,-21.534,-21.825,-20.639,-20.59,
32,5,-21.423,-21.844,-22.352,-21.992,-21.527,-22.609,-21.315,-20.621,
33,0,-21.38,-21.652,-21.927,-21.958,-20.562,-21.574,-22.638,-20.577,
33,1,-21.4,-21.735,-22.389,-21.811,-20.592,-21.576,-21.825,-20.595,
33,2,-21.345,-18.344,-22.442,-21.956,-20.552,-21.456,-21.672,-20.589,
33,3,-21.114,-21.459,-21.844,-21.975,-20.614,-21.566,-22.607,-20.581,
33,4,-21.244,-21.852,-22.262,-21.883,-20.6,-21.555,-22.146,-20.32,
33,5,-21.287,-21.602,-22.221,-21.881,-20.287,-21.587,-22.642,-20.253,
34,0,-21.223,-21.813,-22.446,-22.112,-21.583,-22.588,-22.677,-21.532,
34,1,-20.967,-21.711,-22.347,-22.023,-21.559,-22.645,-22.66,-21.635,
34,2,-21.3,-21.49,-22.191,-21.827,-21.546,-22.672,-22.637,-21.565,
34,3,-21.608,-21.914,-22.347,-22.142,-21.155,-22.648,-22.601,-21.557,
34,4,-21.221,-21.705,-22.495,-22.07,-21.568,-22.635,-22.635,-21.563,
34,5,-21.691,-21.776,-22.78,-21.819,-21.557,-22.594,-22.13,-21.564,
35,0,-22.202,-22.356,-22.424,-21.79,-20.657,-21.561,-21.427,-19.727,
35,1,-22.308,-22.247,-22.413,-21.948,-20.608,-21.57,-21.565,-19.728,
35,2,-22.228,-21.842,-22.365,-21.797,-20.581,-20.85,-21.458,-19.726,
35,3,-21.889,-22.363,-22.334,-21.717,-20.594,-21.476,-21.548,-19.718,
35,4,-22.03,-22.358,-22.363,-21.374,-20.831,-21.512,-21.567,-19.725,
35,5,-22.091,-22.019,-22.371,-21.941,-20.618,-21.499,-21.545,-19.714,
36,0,-22.18,-19.09,-22.198,-21.727,-20.582,-21.669,-21.556,-20.588,
36,1,-22.393,-19.955,-22.398,-21.809,-20.604,-21.589,-21.572,-20.039,
36,2,-21.823,-21.682,-22.448,-22.206,-20.589,-21.58,-21.559,-20.549,
36,3,-22.011,-19.54,-22.395,-21.921,-20.446,-21.553,-21.549,-19.824,
36,4,-21.83,-15.43,-21.969,-21.47,-19.661,-21.543,-21.56,-20.593,
36,5,-22.328,-22.119,-22.072,-21.137,-19.716,-21.549,-21.586,-20.593,
37,0,-22.433,-21.821,-21.91,-22.2,-20.597,-21.594,-21.552,-19.764,
37,1,-22.398,-22.219,-21.944,-21.819,-20.592,-21.716,-21.583,-19.961,
37,2,-22.356,-21.817,-21.994,-22.384,-20.589,-21.576,-21.59,-19.862,
37,3,-22.365,-20.818,-21.725,-22.03,-20.568,-21.579,-21.571,-19.72,
37,4,-22.341,-21.929,-21.825,-21.854,-20.587,-21.567,-21.544,-19.788,
37,5,-22.217,-21.858,-22.249,-22.271,-20.16,-21.554,-21.589,-19.835,
38,0,-22.367,-21.78,-22.202,-21.739,-20.591,-21.552,-21.607,-20.559,
38,1,-22.356,-22.174,-22.319,-22.165,-20.592,-21.372,-21.551,-20.613,
38,2,-22.136,-21.39,-22.382,-21.805,-20.893,-21.569,-21.549,-20.604,
38,3,-21.9,-21.604,-22.119,-21.86,-20.897,-21.345,-21.567,-20.608,
38,4,-21.811,-21.799,-22.114,-21.455,-20.598,-21.553,-21.558,-20.569,
38,5,-21.834,-21.809,-22.471,-21.937,-20.635,-21.553,-21.672,-20.602,
39,0,-20.995,-22.282,-22.049,-21.823,-22.633,-22.647,-22.631,-20.64,
39,1,-21.12,-22.258,-22.325,-21.258,-21.565,-22.634,-22.657,-20.894,
39,2,-21.179,-21.838,-22.384,-21.994,-21.95,-22.576,-22.62,-20.644,
39,3,-21.258,-22.08,-22.363,-21.697,-22.64,-22.627,-21.938,-20.57,
39,4,-21.339,-21.827,-22.265,-21.48,-22.641,-21.702,-22.636,-21.556,
39,5,-21.347,-21.813,-22.021,-21.701,-21.557,-22.644,-22.638,-20.748,
40,0,-21.187,-22.153,-22.352,-21.819,-21.639,-20.589,-21.568,-19.72,
40,1,-21.496,-22.308,-22.275,-21.415,-21.163,-21.564,-21.582,-19.721,
40,2,-21.183,-21.854,-22.297,-21.805,-21.583,-21.557,-21.548,-19.734,
40,3,-21.54,-22.319,-22.258,-21.616,-21.558,-20.81,-21.601,-19.801,
40,4,-21.53,-22.317,-22.404,-21.574,-21.56,-21.015,-21.557,-19.834,
40,5,-21.37,-22.243,-22.44,-21.039,-21.571,-21.52,-21.557,-19.711,
41,0,-21.343,-22.044,-22.063,-21.786,-21.55,-22.628,-21.786,-21.558,
41,1,-21.737,-21.983,-22.142,-21.832,-21.55,-22.632,-21.605,-21.584,
41,2,-20.947,-22.363,-22.343,-21.606,-21.564,-22.616,-21.73,-21.553,
41,3,-21.135,-22.08,-22.343,-21.803,-21.558,-22.642,-21.714,-21.553,
41,4,-21.512,-21.772,-22.025,-21.803,-21.496,-22.636,-22.189,-21.559,
41,5,-21.127,-22.314,-22.308,-21.846,-20.813,-22.647,-21.716,-21.588,
42,0,-21.929,-19.589,-22.172,-21.823,-21.543,-21.589,-21.556,-20.309,
42,1,-22.015,-21.889,-22.354,-21.827,-21.545,-21.56,-21.569,-19.748,
42,2,-22.183,-21.632,-21.817,-21.506,-21.341,-21.545,-21.556,-19.725,
42,3,-22.347,-22.413,-22.308,-21.325,-20.784,-21.555,-21.567,-19.707,
42,4,-22.354,-22.125,-22.108,-21.809,-20.921,-21.526,-21.568,-19.723,
42,5,-22.091,-22.347,-22.448,-21.846,-21.536,-21.542,-21.547,-19.495,
43,0,-21.378,-21.707,-22.382,-21.846,-20.687,-21.555,-20.808,-20.194,
43,1,-21.162,-21.788,-22.338,-21.844,-20.631,-21.465,-21.534,-20.563,
43,2,-21.127,-21.656,-22.354,-21.838,-20.712,-21.598,-20.698,-20.591,
43,3,-20.445,-22.328,-22.241,-21.756,-20.826,-21.562,-20.606,-20.58,
43,4,-21.343,-22.356,-22.136,-21.766,-20.638,-21.607,-20.628,-20.122,
43,5,-21.429,-21.403,-22.121,-21.809,-20.043,-21.552,-20.586,-20.581,
44,0,-22.142,-21.64,-22.104,-21.803,-20.577,-21.557,-21.232,-19.148,
44,1,-21.405,-21.766,-22.347,-21.674,-19.715,-21.592,-21.146,-19.309,
44,2,-22.341,-21.811,-22.341,-21.554,-20.552,-21.568,-20.587,-19.7,
44,3,-22.31,-21.823,-22.14,-21.834,-20.576,-21.564,-21.535,-19.709,
44,4,-22.044,-21.819,-22.446,-21.312,-20.576,-21.604,-21.49,-19.249,
44,5,-21.875,-22.236,-22.299,-21.807,-20.591,-21.615,-21.535,-18.94,
45,0,-21.025,-19.526,-22.415,-21.875,-20.591,-21.59,-21.655,-19.096,
45,1,-20.938,-21.832,-22.314,-21.813,-19.749,-21.558,-21.69,-18.936,
45,2,-20.845,-21.813,-22.321,-21.819,-20.566,-21.524,-21.595,-19.243,
45,3,-21.097,-21.937,-22.435,-21.821,-20.488,-21.552,-21.599,-19.181,
45,4,-21.225,-21.865,-22.347,-21.793,-19.911,-21.574,-21.607,-18.947,
45,5,-20.658,-21.709,-22.371,-21.902,-19.819,-21.559,-21.557,-19.733,
46,0,-21.977,-21.958,-22.428,-21.788,-20.589,-21.529,-21.473,-19.758,
46,1,-21.784,-21.838,-22.515,-21.429,-20.606,-21.541,-21.543,-20.389,
46,2,-21.925,-21.682,-22.376,-21.325,-19.947,-21.53,-21.562,-20.602,
46,3,-21.944,-21.79,-22.42,-21.566,-20.53,-21.565,-21.579,-20.585,
46,4,-22.301,-22.211,-22.323,-21.183,-20.348,-21.544,-21.669,-20.59,
46,5,-21.318,-22.034,-22.332,-20.843,-20.571,-21.602,-21.616,-20.464,
47,0,-21.065,-21.83,-22.378,-22.148,-20.579,-21.548,-21.85,-20.463,
47,1,-20.584,-21.838,-21.941,-21.634,-20.575,-21.565,-21.573,-20.581,
47,2,-20.865,-17.656,-22.376,-21.758,-20.041,-21.548,-21.56,-19.848,
47,3,-21.086,-21.343,-22.325,-21.542,-20.577,-21.539,-21.607,-20.577,
47,4,-21.063,-21.832,-22.4,-21.811,-20.598,-21.562,-22.636,-20.535,
47,5,-21.269,-21.892,-22.343,-21.819,-20.567,-21.577,-22.637,-20.581,
48,0,-22.358,-21.294,-22.172,-22.123,-21.625,-22.62,-22.074,-20.632,
48,1,-22.245,-21.628,-21.846,-21.916,-21.595,-22.65,-22.485,-20.631,
48,2,-21.908,-21.687,-22.157,-21.867,-21.914,-22.64,-22.64,-20.633,
48,3,-22.36,-21.411,-22.26,-22.116,-22.099,-22.386,-22.65,-21.245,
48,4,-22.196,-21.815,-22.273,-21.817,-21.599,-22.073,-22.642,-20.688,
48,5,-22.395,-21.788,-22.338,-21.83,-21.902,-22.649,-21.598,-20.622,
49,0,-20.877,-22.367,-22.269,-21.074,-21.576,-21.576,-22.65,-20.921,
49,1,-21.514,-22.247,-22.367,-21.461,-21.553,-21.57,-22.638,-21.005,
49,2,-20.88,-21.766,-22.282,-21.48,-21.563,-21.554,-22.642,-21.473,
49,3,-20.869,-21.858,-22.38,-21.705,-22.015,-21.697,-22.662,-20.726,
49,4,-21.484,-21.933,-22.161,-21.803,-21.609,-21.587,-22.652,-20.776,
49,5,-21.19,-22.025,-22.347,-21.719,-21.68,-21.494,-22.638,-20.612,
50,0,-20.854,-17.194,-22.034,-21.409,-20.607,-21.554,-21.573,-19.761,
50,1,-20.66,-21.801,-22.482,-21.77,-20.584,-21.479,-21.499,-20.197,
50,2,-21.082,-18.262,-22.234,-21.854,-20.51,-21.561,-21.511,-19.736,
50,3,-21.413,-21.476,-22.352,-22.019,-20.584,-20.613,-21.554,-19.743,
50,4,-21.164,-22.323,-22.312,-21.782,-20.605,-20.694,-21.564,-19.765,
50,5,-21.101,-19.237,-21.95,-21.923,-20.619,-21.56,-21.549,-20.127,
,,,,,,,,,,
Summery Results,,,,,,,,,,
,,MSE ChA,MSE ChB,MSE ChC,MSE ChD,MSE_remote ChA,MSE_remote ChB,MSE_remote ChC,MSE_remote ChD,
,Average MSE per Channel,-21.518,-21.691,-22.27,-21.697,-21.072,-21.715,-21.663,-20.534,
,Mask-Min MSE for test,-12,-12,-12,-12,-17.5,-17.5,-17.5,-17.5,
,Pass/Fail Status,Pass,Pass,Pass,Pass,Pass,Pass,Pass,Pass,
```

So, if I manually open the CSV and delete the bottom section, this MWE code below works fine:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

%Graph/Chart stuff!!
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz} % To generate the plot from csv
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % Allows to place the legend below plot
\usepgfplotslibrary{units} % Allows to enter the units nicely
\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Data Output - Graphed (Main Channel)}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth,
          grid=major,
          grid style={dashed,gray!30},
          xlabel=Iterations,
          ylabel=Decibels,
          y unit=\si{\decibel},
          legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
          x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,blue]   table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE ChA,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,orange]     table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE ChB,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,green]  table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE ChC,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,brown]  table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE ChD,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot[red] (0,-12) -- (300,-12);
        \legend{ChannelA - Main,ChannelB - Main,ChannelC - Main,ChannelD - Main,Pass/Fail Limit}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Mean Square Energy (Main Channel)}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\subsection{Data Output - Graphed (Aux Channel)}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth,
          grid=major,
          grid style={dashed,gray!30},
          xlabel=Iterations,
          ylabel=Decibels,
          y unit=\si{\decibel},
          legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north},
          x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}
        ]
        \addplot [mark=*,blue]      table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE_remote ChA,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,orange]        table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE_remote ChB,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,green]     table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE_remote ChC,col sep=comma] {mse.csv}; 
        \addplot [mark=*,brown]     table[x expr=\coordindex,y=MSE_remote ChD,col sep=comma] {mse.csv};
        \addplot[red] (0,-17.5) -- (300,-17.5);
        \legend{ChannelA - Aux,ChannelB - Aux,ChannelC - Aux,ChannelD - Aux,Pass/Fail Limit}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Mean Square Energy (Main Channel)}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

How do I make PGFPlots only read 301 lines, with header and STOP at that point.
I understand that it's trying to do a "jump" on that blank line, then choking on the non-numerical data below it.  I just want it to stop importing at that point.  Does one of the PGFPlots "empty lines" arguments do this?  I couldn't get it to work. =(  like, "empty lines=halt" or something?

Also, could I "have my cake and eat it too" and also parse a file that was less than 301 but still contained that footer section?

Error output:

```
NOTE: coordinate (1Y3.0e2],) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. (
see also unbounded coords=jump). 
NOTE: coordinate (1Y3.01e2],) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter. 
(see also unbounded coords=jump). 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input 'MSE ChA' as a floating point n
umber, sorry. The unreadable part was near 'MSE ChA'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

I am on Windows using MiKTeX Portable.  Can any guru steer me in the right direction here?  I am sure there's a way but I am new at this!  I did my best to search for similar questions on here, but I didn't see anything applicable. At least I hope.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. This seems to be a duplicate question of e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287453/regression-on-a-portion-of-the-graph-with-columns. There I already commented that currently there is no way to ignore lines in the middle or the end while reading or processing a data table.

Comment: I accepted your answer, thanks!  I wish that other question had something that came up on one of my many searches!  My thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I already stated in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343513/pgfplots-csv-read-first-301-lines-only-or-skip-last-n#comment843508_343513) there is currently no way to ignore lines in the middle or the end while reading or processing a data table (in PGFPlots *directly*).

But since you seem to be familiar with gnuplot you can extract the data using the `raw gnuplot` feature of PGFPlots.

Said that: If you know a solution to your "bonus question" (what when less than 301 lines are plotted before the footer lines?) in gnuplot, it should be simple for you to apply it. I thought that `every :::0::0` should do the trick, but it seems that "the comma line" isn't detected as an empty line, so the block detection fails ...

(For the future I would recommend to move the footer lines to the top and just "comment" them by prepending the lines by a comment char like `#` or `%`. By that you will be able to plot the data directly without the detour using gnuplot.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14 and gnuplot v5.0 patchlevel 3
% (data file given in the question <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343513>)
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{units}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
    % create custom cycle list which is later used for the "channels" in the data table
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my colors}{
        blue\\
        orange\\
        green\\
        brown\\
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=\linewidth,
            grid=major,
            grid style={
                dashed,
                gray!30,
            },
            xlabel=Iterations,
            ylabel=Decibels,
            y unit=\si{\decibel},
            legend style={
                at={(0.5,-0.2)},
                anchor=north,
            },
            x tick label style={
                rotate=90,
                anchor=east,
            },
            % use/apply custom cycle list
            cycle list name=my colors,
        ]

            % use `raw gnuplot` feature to extract the first 301 lines of the data table
            \foreach \i in {3,...,6} {
                \addplot+ [
                    mark=*,
                ] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
                    set datafile separator ",";
                    plot "mse.csv" using \i\space every ::1::301;
%                    % this should be the solution for the bonus question
%                    % (but it seems that there is no "empty" line in the
%                    %  data table ...)
%                    plot "mse.csv" using \i\space every :::0::0;
                };
            }
            \addplot [red] (0,-12) -- (300,-12);

            \legend{
                ChannelA -- Main,
                ChannelB -- Main,
                ChannelC -- Main,
                ChannelD -- Main,
                Pass/Fail Limit,
            }

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: So, I learned a **lot** from reading your answer.  I like the formatting/indents, the color list, and the loop is a lot cleaner.  I did not understand that you had almost full gnuplot syntax when calling it like this, and that will work as I found out I will have 301 lines no matter what.  I may still further investigate the root cause which is essentially a not ideally formatted CSV, as you can see.  But this gets me up and running today, so hooray! Thank you for taking the time =)

Comment: You are welcome. And for the record: Besides "only" accepting my answer, you could also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it by clicking on the up-arrow on the top left of the answer (above the number). (Maybe this only will work when you have a bit more reputation yourself; I am not sure about that ...)

Comment: When my rep is high enough I surely will.