# pgfplotstable: Calculate linear regression based on meta

Tags: pgfplotstable

How am I able to calculate two linear regressions basing on the meta-data?

In my example I want to have one linear regression for the green points and one for the red points.

```
\documentclass[preview, border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatable.txt}
one two letter
 9   7   g
 9   6   g
 8   1   g
 7   3   g
 6   5   g
 6   5   g
 5   2   g
 4   8   r
 3   9   r
 3   2   r
 3   1   r
 2   3   r
 1   2   r
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scatter/classes={
        g={mark=*,green},
        r={mark=*,red}
    }
]
\addplot [scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic] table [x=one, y=two, meta=letter] {datatable.txt};
\addplot [blue, no markers] table [x=one,y={create col/linear regression={y=two}}] {datatable.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

*This can't be done with only pgfplotstable.*

> See [Regression on a portion of the graph with columns (at the beginning)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287453/regression-on-a-portion-of-the-graph-with-columns-at-the-beginning/343740#343740), which indicates the regression
>   applies to the whole table. The regression cannot be applied to just
>   part of the table. There is a workaround there that uses gnuplot, but
>   your solution works too.

-- [Ross](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89098/ross)

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

*I still don't know, how to do this with only one file, but here is my solution which uses two files*

**Result:**

[image: two linear regression in one image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatableA.txt}
one two letter
 9   7   g
 9   6   g
 8   1   g
 7   3   g
 6   5   g
 6   5   g
 5   2   g
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{datatableB.txt}
one two letter
 4   8   r
 3   9   r
 3   2   r
 3   1   r
 2   3   r
 1   2   r
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scatter/classes={
        g={mark=*,green},
        r={mark=*,red}
    }
]
\addplot [scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic] table [x=one, y=two, meta=letter] {datatableA.txt};
\addplot [scatter,only marks,scatter src=explicit symbolic] table [x=one, y=two, meta=letter] {datatableB.txt};
\addplot [green, no markers] table [x=one,y={create col/linear regression={y=two}}] {datatableA.txt};
\addplot [red, no markers] table [x=one,y={create col/linear regression={y=two}}] {datatableB.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343740, which indicates the regression applies to the whole table. The regression cannot be applied to just part of the table. There is a workaround there that uses gnuplot, but your solution works too.